# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'echo' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed all the pipeline plugins,

but I am still getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'echo' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, ArtifactoryMavenBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, build, checkout, collectEnv, copyRemoteArtifacts, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep, emailext, emailextrecipients, getArtifactoryServer, git, input, libraryResource, load, milestone, newArtifactoryServer, newBuildInfo, newGradleBuild, newMavenBuild, parallel, properties, publishBuildInfo, readTrusted, stage, triggerRemoteJob, withCredentials, xrayScanBuild] or symbols [all, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, junit, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [Artifactory, currentBuild, env, params, scm]
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1280)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1174)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
```

Am I missing some plugin?

Comment: What does your Jenkinsfile look like? Are you using declarative pipeline syntax? I'm not sure if `echo` is available there.

Comment: Call me stupid; I emptied plugins directory inside workspace directory and copied *.hpi files back to workspace/plugins and restarted jenkins, all errors seemed to go away. PS: I always install plugins offline, so I always know what is going inside as well as I'd have extra copy of hpi file

Comment: Here is how I resolved this issue. Hope this can be helpful. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592197/getting-error-after-jenkins-update-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-such-dsl-met/67283730#67283730)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you don't have the [Pipeline Basic Steps Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps) installed, as none of the [steps provided](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/), including `echo`, by the plugin seem to be listed in the error message.

Or, the plugin is installed, but failed to load as one of its dependencies was removed or failed to load.  If you're an admin, you should see a warning about that at the top-right of each page, or in the [logs](https://jenkins.io/redirect/find-jenkins-logs/).

Comment: lifesaver answer for jenkins user guide follower.